# Regex in Apache 'if' directive ... what's wrong here?

Tags: regex, apache, if-statement, configuration

*(A possible bug in Apache is now suspected ... see below.)*

Here's the statements:  *(Apache 2.4)*

```
<IfDefine !SERVER_TYPE>
    Define SERVER_TYPE prod
</IfDefine>
<If "${SERVER_TYPE} !~ /prod|demo|test/">   <===error here===
    Error "Define 'SERVER_TYPE' is hosed'"
</If>
```

Apache complains about the IF:

```
Cannot parse condition clause: syntax error, unexpected T_OP_NRE, expecting '('
```

I can guess that T_OP_NRE refers to "negated regular-expression" *i.e.* "!~" but I can't for the life of me figure out what's the syntax-error in that statement!  *(And, incidentally, "=~" produces [almost] the same message.)*

Apache is recognizing the ${SERVER_TYPE} syntax as I can confirm if I misspell the identifier.  The documentation for <DEFINE> expressly states that "${ident}" not "%{ident}" syntax should be used, as I have done.

What's wrong with my syntax, and why does Apache expect a left-parenthesis?

---

I am cautiously beginning to believe that this is actually a **BUG(!)** in Apache/2.4.12 because the parse-error only occurs when "${DEFINED_SYMBOL}" is used.  It will complain and do all the right things if the symbol is not defined (so, it knows what it's looking at ...), but it gives a nonsensical *(to me ...)* message as-shown if, and only if, this construct is on the left-hand side.

An apparent workaround is to put the symbol in single quotes, e.g.:

```
<If "'${SERVER_TYPE}' != /prod/demo/test/">
```

... but so-far in my testing I don't think that it is matching the regex correctly.  In fact, I'm not yet sure *what* is going on, because the following is considered to be a *non*-match ("true"):

```
<If "'prod' !~ /prod|demo|test/">
```

The regex syntax can be shown to be correct via this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -e 'my $var = "prod"; if ($var =~ /prod|demo|test/) {print "yes\n";}'
```

... which prints "yes."

---

P.S. The "${IDENT}" syntax *is* correct (versus "%{}", which is not) in the case of a Defined symbol.

Comment: and it's blue, because it's a `"..."` string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this syntax:

```
<If "'${SERVER_TYPE}' !~ m#(prod|demo|test)#">
    #Error "Define 'SERVER_TYPE' is hosed"
    RedirectMatch /old /new/
</If>
```