# How do I use a custom variable in an If-Else statement inside an Apache config?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Here's my code (I've commented out the if-else part as it's not working)

snippets/contents of my config files

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/staff.vhost**

```
Define host_domain "staff"

Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/stage_template.vhost
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/stage_template.vhost**

```
    #<If "${host_domain} == 'main'">
    #    ServerAlias stage.myhost.com
    #</If>
    #<Else>
        ServerAlias stage-${host_domain}.myhost.com
    #</Else>
```

${host_domain} can have 3 possible values: main or staff or customer

I have tried:

- ${host_domain}: I get this error

  AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/stage_template.vhost: Cannot parse condition clause: syntax error, unexpected T_OP_STR_EQ, expecting '('
- %{host_domain}: I get another error

  AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/stage_template.vhost:
  Cannot parse condition clause: Parse error near '%'

Thanks!

edit: I was using this [page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) as guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<If "false">
...
</If>
```

Take a look at [Expressions in Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html).

**EDIT :**

if ***host_domain*** is not a self created variable make all upper case `${HOST_DOMAIN}`.

and wrap it with single quotations:

```
#<If "'${host_domain}' == 'main'">
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36020563/7470786).

Comment: I'm not sure where's the comparison in your sample code.